# GCP creates random replicator instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have created a free trial instance in GCP. Now I am seeing 2 instance in VM instance dashboard.

One is the instance that I am using and other is  **ce-replicator-goo16-2e8##f6b**. I tried to delete this instance but it automatically comes up again. I am not sure why this instance is for. Will I be charged for this instance as well.

IF anyone have idea on this, Please help.

Thanks
J

Comment: Did you use [CloudEndure](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vm-migration/using-cloud-endure) migration service to bring your instance into GCP? 

If so it seems like [Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vm-migration/using-cloud-endure#serviceaccount) having Owner permission recreating the instance "ce-replicator-goo16-2e8##f6b". If this is the situation, you need to delete the service account used for migration and then would be able to delete the instance.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yeah, I have used cloudendure migration.I have deleted both the instance and service account. Hopefully, It should not come back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens when you are using CloudEndure migration service to bring your instance into GCP. In such cases, Service Account having Owner permission recreating the instance "ce-replicator-goo16-2e8##f6b". Deleting the "service account" used for migration would allow deleting those temporary instance.